# Circular rebalance through 1 of 7 channels always times out

Tags: lightning-network, lightning-routing

I have the following 8 channels open

[image: channels]

I am able to do a circular rebalance through the first 6 as expected

The bottom 2 channels are to the same node

Every time I try to do a circular rebalance (tried all paths through the other channels) through either of the bottom 2 channels, the payment times out

1. Has 1ml.com done something to prevent me from using these channels?
2. If so, leaving these channels open could lead to unnecessary failures through those routes when someone attempts to use my node for routing?